# MapView display blank

Tags: android, api, google-maps, android-mapview

I'm using Google Maps Android API v2 with MapView . When I run MapView . It displays blank . What is happening ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the fragment element with the MapView. The correct way would be a layout file like this:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for help ! But it still crash

Comment: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(805): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.MapView/com.example.MapView.MyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView

Answer (score 1):

A MapView is not a subclass of Fragment, so you cannot use it with the `<fragment />` tag.

And yes, Maps v2 is very different from Maps v1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `MapView` then your activity must extend `MapActivity`. Right now you have:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
```

This will work when loading a Google Maps v2 fragment but will not work when you are loading a Google Maps v1 `MapView`. A `MapView` MUST be created within an activity that extends `MapActivity`. Change your activity to

```
public class MyActivity extends MapActivity
```

This should fix the mapview issue.

Comment: Google Maps Android API v2 not use MapActivity  . It using for Google Maps Android API v1

Comment: I know that v2 does not need MapActivity. Can you make the question clearer? Are you trying to use that one activity to display both a MapView and Fragment for v1 and v2 of the maps api?

Comment: Both of them use Google Maps Android API v2 . I don't know how to use MapView in Google Maps Android API v2 .